# How to check if new record has added to db in controller/views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im creating a simple messaging application.
So far there are users conversations and messages.
In the index page of the messages i render all the messages of a specific conversation.The thing is,i dont know how to check if new messages have been added so i reload the page to make them appear. Some help?

Comment: Refreshing page is one way to go. Next step is periodically doing some ajax requests in the background. They will check for new messages, fetch them and update the page. Next step is to pro-actively push new messages to the browser, using some kind of websockets technology. So yes, your keywords for googling are: `"rails ajax request"`.

Comment: Checkout rails 5 Action cable http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: yes. As Sergio pointed out. What you need is to asynchronously inform your page for changes. For that, you can either make AJAX HTTP requests from the page.. or you can maintain a websocket (a full duplex connection from client to server) on page and server can send the events to page to inform about changes - ActionCable in Rails 5 which @TonyVincent pointed.